# Symfony 3 YAML routing not working

Tags: php, routes, symfony

this is the code for my front controller:

```
<?php

namespace SystemBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SystemController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('SystemBundle:Pages:index.html.twig');
    }
    public function pkgsAction(){
        return $this->render('SystemBundle:Pages:pkg.html.twig');
    }
    public function aboutAction(){
        return $this->render('SystemBundle:Pages:about.html.twig');
    }
    public function contactAction(){
        return $this->render('SystemBundle:Pages:contact.html.twig');
    }
}
```

and the following is my routing.yml file inside my SystemBundle>Resources>config :

```
system_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: SystemBundle:System:index }

system_about:
    path: /about
    defaults: { _controller: SystemBundle:System:about}

system_contact:
    path: /contact
    defaults: { _controller: SystemBundle:System:contact}

system_pkg:
    path: /pkgs
    defaults: { _controller: SystemBundle:System:pkgs}
```

Everything seems okay and I can access the localhost:8000 but not the other pages like localhost:8000/contact, etc.

They give out a 404 error and an exception: 
[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy7p6.png)

Please help...

Comment: You should really try `annotation`. Makes *routing* a breeze, especially for newbies to Symfony. I'm working on a brief example that I will post in a minute.

Comment: What do you have in app/config/routing.yml ?

Comment: Try add next to your app/config/routing.yml:
system:
    resource: "@SystemBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

Comment: If all you need is rendering a template, consider using a TemplateController from the Frameworkbundle: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html

Answer (score 0):

In your *routing.yml* file, set `type` to *annotation*. See the [Symfony Routing Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) for more information.

```
// app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@SystemBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Then you can add annotation routes, very easily I might add, in your controller.. like so:

```
<?php
namespace SystemBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SystemController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('SystemBundle:Pages:index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/pkg")
     */
    public function pkgsAction()
    {
        return $this->render('SystemBundle:Pages:pkg.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/about")
     */
    public function aboutAction()
    {
        return $this->render('SystemBundle:Pages:about.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/contact")
     */
    public function contactAction()
    {
        return $this->render('SystemBundle:Pages:contact.html.twig');
    }

}
```

Now you can control your routing right at the class/method level. Personally (and I feel many would agree) this offers a great level of control and clarity over your routes as they're included right there with the method in question.

**Caveat**
Some will argue (for some good reason) that annotations are *bad practice* as they clutter up the method comments, and actually *remove* clarity within said comments. I disagree with this notion. Symfony annotations are clearly different than most standard methods of method commenting as they're required to have a certain syntax, ie. `@route` will not compile; `@Route` must have a capital 'R', for example.

Not to mention, when you're working in a Symfony-based project, you should be aware of the possibility that annotations will be used. This is all part of communication within a development team. if you're being hired, for example, to work on a Symfony-based project, you should really be aware of annotations and they should not confuse you, nor should they confuse the code you're writing.

I'm in favour of route annotations. You'll find they're easy-to-use, and easy to control.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still giving out the same exception/error in the output!

Comment: Can you post your full `routing.yml` file to your original post, please?

Comment: I don't know how, but clearing the cache did the job... Thanks for your help bro :)

Comment: That was my next suggestion. Got wrapped up on something else though. Glad it's working man. You go with annotations in the end? Or you stick with what you had?

Comment: I am surely going to use annotation in my next project, it's good to have it in front of the eye instead of locating the files and directories! YML is a group decision this time!